# Finding optimal Bus Transit Center location

Tags: qgis, network-analyst, routing, location-allocation

My project aims at finding the accessibility of transportation to my university.

I have around 6000 student data points(lat/long coordinates of each 6000 student location) and I have plotted them on QGIS, I have figured out 3 areas in which there are no bus stops or public transport.

I want to do an analysis to set up a transit center in either of these 3 locations so that most of the demand will be covered and students will be able to access these bus routes to reach university.

How can I do it in QGIS? Any Plugin? or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If each of the 6000 students could be assigned a distance along a routed network to each of the 3 proposed transit stops, and you had a distance threshold you wanted to work with, it could be a matter of simply counting which stop serves the most students within that distance threshold and/or creating service areas around the 3 stops and counting how many students are served within each.

We use PGRouting to do this with students and schools, so here I would similarily assign the distance to each student to each transit stop then use SQL to count and group.